# Minimum of rational function

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, rational-functions

Is there a way to find an analytical expression for the minimum of the following nasty function on $[0, \infty)$?

\begin{align*}
Q(u) & =
 \frac{ (u^2 + t_{11} u + t_{11}p_{11}) (u^2 + t_{22} u + t_{22}p_{22} ) (u^2 + u (t_{12} + p_{12}) + t_{12}^2)^4 }{ (u^2 + u (t_{11} + p_{11}) + t_{11}^2)^2  (u^2 + u (t_{22} + p_{22}) + t_{22}^2)^2 (u^2 + t_{12} u + t_{12}p_{12})^2 },
\end{align*}

where $t_{ij} > 0$, $p_{ij} > 0$,  $t_{ij} > p_{ij}$ $i, j = 1, 2.$

Or to say for which parameters there is none?

Comment: $\ln Q$ is still ugly, but easier to differentiate, nonetheless. It still yields a too high degree equation. ($11$th degree, I think).